# Disable HTML column with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with multiple columns and each header column has a check box. I want to disable a column on click of the header checkbox. How can I get the current clicked  from clicked checkbox in  with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('checkbox').attr('checked'))
{
    $(this).parent().hide();
}
```

Please make sure you have linked to jquery

Something like that, please provide Html, if you require more specific help

Comment: <table><thead><th>checkbox</th><th>checkbox</th></thead><tbody>  <tr><td>checkbox</td><td>checkbox</td></tr></tbody></table>

Answer (score 0):

The `target` property of the `event` object will tell you which element was clicked upon. Additionally, if the event handler is bound to the checkbox itself, it will also be available through `this`.

Comment: yes the handler is bound to checkbox.CAn i get the current clicked column from "this".?